# Domino.NotesDocumentCollection - what order are the items in the collection in?

Tags: vb6, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm maintaining a legacy VB6 app that processes messages from Lotus Notes databases. From an instance of NotesDatabase, we obtain a NotesDocumentCollection and loop through the messages thusly:

```
Set domCollection = domDatabase.AllDocuments
Set domDocument = domCollection.GetFirstDocument
'Do something with domDocument
Set domDocument = domCollection.GetNextDocument
'Continue until no more documents
```

My question: Is it possible to know what order the documents will be returned in with the GetFirstDocument and GetNextDocument methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `NotesDocumentCollection` created e.g. from `AllDocuments` is unsorted. If you look at the order then you might discover that documents appear in order of creation. But there is no guarantee for that and mostly not helpful anyway.

If you need a sorted list of documents use `NotesViewEntryCollection` instead together with a sorted view.

If you need only some of the fields from documents put them all in view's columns and access them with `entry.ColumnValues`. This way you get a much higher performance than reading every single document.

Comment: Good answer. If I recall correctly, the NotesDocumentCollection created from AllDocuments is actually in NoteID order; so as you said, it will often appear to be in order of creation, but if/when NoteIDs are re-used then the order will just appear to be random.